# Google Maps V2 API Pegman (Streetview)

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

How can I add the Pegman (little orange guy) to a google map using V2 API, so I can drag him from the google controls onto the map to switch to street view. I can see how to do this in the V3 API but cannot see how to do this in V2

Comment: pegman is the new feature of V3

Answer (score 1):

Although there may be some way to do it, pegman support was only added in Google Maps API v3 according to http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/they-grow-up-so-fast.html.  So even if you figure out a way to do it, I wouldn't rely on it being robust.  Best thing to do, if you need pegman, is to upgrade to API v3.